# How can I load file with hash with WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I use the code to load URL path hash fragment (such as: index.html#/some-hash-path; but WKWebview not load url.

```
let path = "www/index.html"
let page = "#/some-hash-path"
let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(path + page)
self.webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

It seem that it convert # -> %23 which make invalid path

Comment: would you try with  `webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: path + page)`

Comment: @NazmulHasan: It may work but I think construct URL from string simpler and don't need to care with the lifecycle of the webview or app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Construct URL from string work as expected:

```
let path = "www/index.html"
let page = "#/some-hash-path"
guard let parsedUrl = URL(string: Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString + path + page) else {
  return
}
self.webView.loadFileURL(parsedUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck too trying to build the url in an apparently correct way for local files.

The url must be created with `URL(string:)` initializer, prefixing it manually with `file://`, and loaded with `loadFileURL()`.

```
let url = URL(string: "file://\(indexPath)#\(section)")
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```